# Add a file to an MSI

Tags: windows-installer

How can I add a file to a precompiled msi and configure it such that when I run the msi the file is put into the program's application directory?  I can add a file as a stream to the msi using msidb.exe /a but when I run the installer the file doesn't show up anywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Orca](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370557%28VS.85%29.aspx) to edit the msi file to tell the windows installer where to put the file. Read up on the [**File**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368596%28VS.85%29.aspx), [**Directory**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368596%28VS.85%29.aspx) and [**Component**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368007%28VS.85%29.aspx) tables on MSDN and start from there

Comment: Could you please describe your answer in more detail?